# Sympy: Could not solve differential equation. IndexError

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I am currently working on a college project, the goal of the project is to use Euler method for an approximation and I have to compare the exact solution with my approximation.

Currently the user just inputs the differential equation such as y' = 2xy, then i have to solve this ode to get its solution. I have wrote the code like this:

```
xSymbol = sp.symbols("x")
xFunc = sp.Function("f")(xSymbol)
equation = sp.sympify(dataToOperate.equation)
equa = sp.Eq(equation)

classification = sp.classify_ode(equa, xFunc)

print(classification)
```

I first parse with sympify to convert it to expression then i pass it to the Eq method get an equation, but at the moment of passing it to classify_ode It fails to detect the kind of ode, and so i can't use dsolve method too, Can anyone help with this?

I have a jupyter notebook in google colab with a fragment of the code, where you can see that the output is not correct.

[jupyter notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YPauImIVQ_OtgEaepJ3IcHPdM_sk4YmL?usp=sharing)

Comment: I like to see some of the intermediate results.  I can't run most sympy code in my head, and don't always have a sympy session at hand.

Comment: I created a jupyter notebook in google colab, with some of the code running there, is that useful for you? There you can see that the output is wrong.